# cannot add arc pcl on profile 111

Tags: xamarin, nuget, xamarin.forms

i am running vs 2015 xamarin form pcl project 
and a profile 111
i am trying to install https://www.nuget.org/packages/ArcGIS.PCL/5.8.0
which u can see is compatible with profile 111
but guess what happens when i try to install the nuget?
yes thats right ,i get the old

```
Could not install package 'ArcGIS.PCL 5.8.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

yes my nuget is 111 compatable and my profile is 111 and i still get this error!
can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

PCL Profile 111 is not compatible with ArcGIS.PCL 5.8.0.

Profile 111 targets:

```
portable45-net45+win8+wpa81
```

ArcGIS.PCL targets:

```
portable45-net45+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10
```

The Mono and Xamarin frameworks are optional and can be ignored.

The problem is that ArcGIS.PCL only supports Windows 8.1 and above as part of its PCL profile. Whilst PCL profile 111 supports Windows 8 so you need to change your PCL profile or use an older version of ArcGIS.PLC (v4).

Looking at the profiles it seems that PCL profile 151 is compatible.

Profile 151:

```
portable46-net451+win81+wpa81
```

Comment: profile 151 doesnt work on vs 2015 and it asks for update

Comment: ok , here is what works install vs2013 and it will install it for profile 111 just fine

Comment: It does not work for me with VS 2013 and NuGet 2.12 installed. I get the same error - `Could not install package 'ArcGIS.PCL 5.8.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-net45+win+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10'`

Comment: I am using profile 111 in Visual Studio 2013. That is where the error message is from.

Comment: I am on the latest NuGet manager 2.12 for Visual Studio 2013.